# Why is SBA JMX Bean Management reporting an error?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-admin

**Versions:**

- Spring Boot 2.1.0
- Spring Boot Admin 2.1.1

I have everything working with my Spring Boot app reporting to Spring Boot Admin. There is just 1 piece not working and that is JMX Bean Management.   From the docs:

> To interact with JMX-beans in the admin UI you have to include Jolokia
>   in your application. As Jolokia is servlet based there is no support
>   for reactive applications. In case you are using the
>   spring-boot-admin-starter-client it will be pulled in for you, if not
>   add Jolokia to your dependencies.

I understand it does not work with Reactive WebFlux but I am using Servlet Based example using Undertow as my servlet container. Configuration in pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

And as i stated everything is working except 1 thing and that is JMX control.  I get the following error and I can't find any reason or logging as to why?  Any help would be appreciated!

[image: JMX Screenshot]

Answer (score -1):

Start your program with following parameters:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
```

And (if using docker/kubernetes) expose port 1099

Comment: Thanks but that had no effect.